# Mui typescript: custom wrapper with a `component` property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I created a custom wrapper component:

```js
import Box, { BoxProps } from "@mui/material/Box";

type WrapperProps = {
  id: string
} & BoxProps

const Wrapper = (props: WrapperProps) => {
  const {id, children, ...rest} = props
  return <Box {...rest}>{children}</Box>
}
```

I want the `Wrapper` to take a `component` property, so I can use it like:

```js
<Wrapper component={Stack} direction="row">...
```

But now the ts complains that "Property 'direction' does not exist".

How should I defined the `WrapperProps` so I can use the `Wrapper` like a `Box`?

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

You props lack the generics, without them they are set to a default values,

```
export type BoxProps<
  D extends React.ElementType = BoxTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
  P = {},
> = OverrideProps<BoxTypeMap<P, D>, D>;
```

Here `BoxTypeMap['defaultComponent']` and `{}`.
`direction` being defined by `StackTypeMap` it could only return an error here !

So something like this should work.

```
type WrapperProps<D extends React.ElementType, P = {}> = {
  id?: string;
} & BoxProps<D, P>;

const Wrapper = (props: WrapperProps<React.ElementType>) => {
  const { id, children, ...rest } = props;
  return <Box {...rest}>{children}</Box>;
};
```